# C++ Templates and comparing different types

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am trying to write a generic sort function in C++ using templates, but I am stuck in writing the `greater` function which returns true if `lhs > rhs`

```
template <typename T>
bool Sorter<T>::greater(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    return lhs > rhs;
}
```

The above code will take care of simple types such as int, long. What should I do so that the code works for `std::string`, `std::string&`, `const char *`. A code sample will be a great help.

Comment: First off, `return lhs > rhs`.

Comment: All deal with `>`-operator. How do you suppose to mange `std::string`, `std::string&`, `const char *` proceed a lexicographical comparison ?

Comment: Quick note: you can simply use "return (lhs > rhs);".

Comment: There **cannot** be a *truly generic* implementation of `<`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say the only one you'd have to worry about is `const char*`, `std::string` should already have `operator>` defined somewhere... (normally in `<string>`)

For `const char*`, provide a specialization.. e.g..

```
template <>
bool Sorter<const char*>::greater(const char* lhs, const char* rhs)
{
  return std::strcmp(lhs, hs) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to specialize the template for types where the comparison isn't as straight-forward as saying `lgs>rhs`.

Here's how I'd re-write your code:

```
template <typename T>
bool greater(T const& lhs, T const& rhs)
{
    return lhs > rhs;
}
```

and here's how you'd specialize it:

```
template<>
bool greater<string>(string const& lhs, string const& rhs)
{
     //
}
```

membership removed for simplicity.

Note that there already is a `std::greater`.

Answer (score 0):

All those types come with comparison operators. Remember that char is just a 1byte number. For string, lexicographic order is used.

[String comparison](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operators/)